# How can i add multiple elements on a single wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, layout

I want to use wordpress as a cms. Is it possible to define standard layout elements which can be combined to edit the layout of a page similar like other cms like "drupal" for example. Ie you could design a row with a picture on the left, one with a picture on the right and one without a picture. Than I combine these templates in any order to built the layout of the pages main content.

Is this possible, maybe with plugins?

Comment: Absolutely.  You may need to build a template (part of the theme), or you may want to use plugins.  WP is super flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course! You just need to **Edit** the already made template your way or you can **Create** your own **Wordpress Template**. But for that you should be confident with your **HTML & CSS** skills!

Here are some resources you may refer :

http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-build-a-custom-wordpress-theme-from-scratch

http://themeshaper.com/modify-wordpress-themes/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not exactly what i mean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not exactly what i mean. I already created a theme and i can edit the page with the plugin "front-end-editor". Now i want to know if i can split one page in different elements which can be edited seperatly? And if i can create a template for each element and built single pages out of combinations of these elements?